# Windows 2008 R2: Unable to upgrade MySQL 5.5.58

Tags: mysql-5.5, windows-server

We have MySQL 5.5.58 sitting on a Windows 2008 R2 box.

I have downloaded the Installer from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ but nothing happens when I try and upgrade.

At the installer screen, I click on Upgrade and it says one of my products have upgrades available.

I click on catalog and it lists a bunch of Samples and Exercises.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: MySQL 5.5 - EoL 2018 and Windows 2008 R2 - EoL 2020... why do you wish to do this?

Comment: I doubt that you can upgrade from 5.5.58 up to actual version directly. Test does 5.7.33 will upgrade, if true then perform 5.5.58->5.7.33->8.0.24, if not then 5.5.58->5.6.51->5.7.33->8.0.24.

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow the upgrade path and follow the upgrade insructions

From 5.5 to 5.6

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrade-paths.html

rom  5.6 to 5.7

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrade-paths.html

And finally from 5.7 to 8.0

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrade-paths.html

Ther you will find also the upgrade instructions